# Serialize List with EKEvents to a JSON in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I try to serialize a simple List that stores EKEvent. I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop
>   detected for property 'Self' with type 'Foundation.NSDate'. Path
>   '[0].EndDate'.
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, System.Object value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty)
>   [0x00105] in :0
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter. CalculatePropertyValues (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer,
>   System.Object value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract& memberContract,
>   System.Object& memberValue) [0x000c7] in :0
>         at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter writer, System.Object value,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract
>   collectionContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty
>   containerProperty) [0x0003c] in :0

This occurs when I try to use JsonConvert.SerializeObject method.
Any workaround for serializing an EKEvent list?

**EDIT**

Using JsonSerializerSettings works!

However, when I try to Deserialise the object, I get another problem:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type EventKit.EKEvent. @
A class should either have a default constructor,
 one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. 
 Path '[0].ClassHandle', line 1, position 16.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject
   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract objectContract, 
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, 
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, 
   System.String id, System.Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator) [0x000d6] in :0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.
  CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0013b] in :0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.
  CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType
  , Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, 
  Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0006d] in :0
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList (IList list, 
  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract,
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty, System.String id) [0x000cb] in :0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because EKEvent has recursive references for it's properties. You can use **`ReferenceLoopHandling`** setting to specify that the json serializer should ignore self referencing loops:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList, new JsonSerializerSettings
                            { 
                                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                            });
```

You can also set the serializer settings globally so that you don't have to specify it for every call:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
```

You can see full example at Json.NET documentation: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: thanks! It solved the serialiser problem. But When I try to Deserialise, I get another problem. I will add this to my question.

Comment: @Khiem-KimHoXuan: You should probably ask it in a new question.

Comment: @Khiem-KimHoXuan What is your linked settings ? Is it link all assemblies ?

Answer (score 2):

Giorgi's answer answers the first part of your question on how to serialize your data, which you seem to have resolved. However, now you have an issue deserializing it again.

Looking at your stack trace that you have supplied in the opening post it says:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type EventKit.EKEvent. @ A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute

That says a lot about this error in particular. Now, looking at the [EventKit EKEvent API reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/EventKit.EKEvent/), we find the following:

1. All the constructors are marked `protected`
2. There are no constructors that take no arguments

This means, when the `DeserializeObject` method tries to create an instance of EKEvent, it does not have any means to do so. It does not know what arguments to provide.

There are also other problems with the EKEvent class. Even if it had public constructors with no arguments. All the properties it has are marked `read-only`. This means when deserializing the serializer again, has no means of populating the properties with the serialized events.

So instead you have these two options:

1. Create a class wrapping EKEvent or imitating EKEvent and deserialize to that
2. Use the provided EKEventStore to persist EKEvents. [As the API docs describe](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/EventKit.EKEventStore/): "The EventStore is required to perform any operations in EventKit. It can be thought of as the persistent storage, or database, engine for all EventKit data."

The opening post does not describe the reasoning as to why you want to serialize and deserialize this object. However, if you want to communicate it to some API, I would suggest that you go for option 1. as it will not be platform specific and you can make it so that you only communicate relevant data between the App and API saving precious bandwidth.